# Machine epsilon estimation in C

Tags: c, precision, epsilon

I'm new to C and I'm trying to find machine epsilon (1.0 + macheps > 1.0), eta (eta > 0.0) and MAX (MAX < infinity), but my code doesn't work as intended. First of all, macheps is calculated using 80-bit precision. How do I force it to single, double and long double? Secondly, the code doesn't finish calculating the results for double precision at all.

EDIT: Fixed the format error.

```
/* macheps eta max */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#define TYPE long double

int main(void)
{
    TYPE macheps = (TYPE) 1.0;
    TYPE eta = (TYPE) 1.0;
    TYPE maksymilian = (TYPE) 2.0;
    TYPE real_macheps;
    TYPE real_eta;
    TYPE real_maksymilian;

    TYPE something = (TYPE) 1.0 + (TYPE) macheps;

    while ((TYPE) something > (TYPE) 1.0)
    {
        real_macheps = (TYPE) macheps;
        printf("%e ", (TYPE) real_macheps);
        macheps = (TYPE) macheps/(TYPE) 2.0;
        something = (TYPE) 1.0 + (TYPE) macheps;
    }
    printf("%e\n", (TYPE) real_macheps);

    while ((TYPE) eta > (TYPE) 0.0)
    {
        real_eta = (TYPE) eta;
        eta = (TYPE) eta/(TYPE) 2.0;
    }
    printf("%e\n", (TYPE) real_eta);

    while ((TYPE) maksymilian != INFINITY)
    {
        (real_maksymilian) = (TYPE) maksymilian;
        maksymilian = (TYPE) maksymilian*(TYPE) 2.0;
    }
    real_maksymilian = (TYPE) real_maksymilian * (TYPE) (2.0-(TYPE) real_macheps);
    printf("%e\n", (TYPE) real_maksymilian);
}
```

EDIT2: Shouldn't the above code force precision? What am I missing?

EDIT3: Still doesn't give correct macheps for long double.

Comment: It is more robust and portable to forbid usage outside the minimum standard C requirements. Ex: if you have an int variable that may overflow, watch it so that it doesn't overflow beyond the minimal required precison from the standard even if the machine allows it. This ensure an architecture/platform independent behavior and is easier to maintain and debug. If you are performing scientific computing and want as much precision as possible, in my experience, the algorithms are typically more severe a bottleneck than machine precicion.

Comment: Never use `main()`, instead, you can use `int main(void)` .

Comment: Why estimate? Use FLT_EPSILON and siblings.

Comment: Because that's the point of the exercise. To confirm that they are the same.=]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You program will invoke undefined behavior. In C, `long` means `long int` and not `long double`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Now it does finish, but single and double still give wrong machine epsilon (80-bit). How do I force 32-bit and 64-bit? And long double still give wrong answers to each one of them.

Comment: Editted it again, but it still doesn't give correct macheps for long double.

Comment: Your format specifier for `long double` is seem to be wrong. Try to change it by `%Le`.

Comment: The problem is with the values used for calculations, not the printed output.

Comment: If you will try to print a value with a format specifier other than that is defined for that value then it will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`long` is shorthand for `long signed int` and therefore an integer type. Use `long double` instead.

Depending on how numbers that cannot be represented are rounded, `(1.0 + machepsfloat) > 1.0` might always be true. Check `FLT_ROUNDS` from [`<float.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/float.h.html) to determine the rounding behaviour of your implementation.

Comment: I made a second edit of the code. What am I missing? Why isn't the precision force by the selected TYPE?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post the corrected code. I had to do a work-around, but it works:

```
/* macheps eta max */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#define TYPE long double /* printf 'e' for float and double, 'Le' for long double */
/* used_type: float 0, double 1, long double 2 */
int main(void)
{
    int used_type = 2;
    TYPE macheps = (TYPE) 1.0;
    TYPE eta = (TYPE) 1.0;
    TYPE maksymilian = (TYPE) 1.0;
    TYPE real_macheps = 0.0;
    TYPE real_eta = 0.0;
    TYPE real_maksymilian = 0.0;
    TYPE something = (TYPE) 1.0 + (TYPE) macheps;

    while ((TYPE) something > (TYPE) 1.0)
    {
        real_macheps = (TYPE) macheps;
        macheps = (TYPE) macheps/(TYPE) 2.0;
        something = (TYPE) 1.0 + (TYPE) macheps;
    }

    while ((TYPE) eta > (TYPE) 0.0)
    {
        real_eta = (TYPE) eta;
        eta = (TYPE) eta/(TYPE) 2.0;
    }

    while ((TYPE) maksymilian != INFINITY)
    {
        (real_maksymilian) = (TYPE) maksymilian;
        maksymilian = (TYPE) maksymilian*(TYPE) 2.0;
    }
    real_maksymilian = (TYPE) real_maksymilian * (TYPE) (2.0-(TYPE) real_macheps);

    if (used_type == 2)
    {
        printf("%Le\n", (TYPE) real_macheps);
        printf("%Le\n", (TYPE) real_eta);
        printf("%Le\n", (TYPE) real_maksymilian);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%e\n", (TYPE) real_macheps);
        printf("%e\n", (TYPE) real_eta);
        printf("%e\n", (TYPE) real_maksymilian);
    }
}
```